# Creating a dictionary's key value that corresponds to a function efficiently

Tags: python

How would I create a dictionary that makes it so that the key corresponds to a function. I need to do this because I'm creating a text rpg, and there are commands that said by the user that does things of course. So, at every time that I get the user's input, instead of having 20 if statements checking if it's a specific string then running a script for each possibility, I can use the user's input as a key to my dictionary and run the corresponding function. My first thought about doing this was like so:

```
def attack(enemy):
    ...

def ...


commands = {'attack': attack,
            ...}
```

But this seems like poorly written code, I'm repeating my function's variable name twice and I end up with function variables that will never be used.
Is there some better way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "function variables that will never be used"? Maybe you're not aware that Python never copies implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is basically dictionaries all the way down, so there are a variety of ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. The most straightforward approach is probably this (note that I moved your function into a class):

```py
class Operations:
    def attack(self, enemy): ...

op = Operations()

fn = getattr(op, "attack")
fn(enemy)
```

Comment: `op.attack()` would also work in this scenario

Comment: Indeed, though the OP is trying to capture commands from user input, so the specific function to call isn't necessarily known in advance.

Comment: oh yea, I forgot about that

Answer (score 1):

You could make the dict more easily by using functions' `__name__` attributes in a comprehension.

```
commands = {f.__name__: f for f in [attack, ...]}
```

And just in case you need any keys that are also Python keywords, you can add them in the next step, for example:

```
def break_(object_):
    ...

commands['break'] = break_
```